# java.util.NoSuchElementException when working with .equals, arraylist and reading file with scanner

Tags: java, file, arraylist, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I'm attempting to populate an arraylist of strings with a text file that contains spaces, such that each string in the arraylist would contain a space between the first and second numbers in it, and no leading or trailing spaces. I am unfortunately running into the following error sequence when running it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at scannerTest.main(scannerTest.java:26)
```

The following is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class scannerTest 

{

private static ArrayList<String> myStore = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int id = 0;
    int inv = 0;
    boolean idStarted = false;
    boolean idFinished = false;
    try 
    {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("file50.txt"));
        System.out.println("File:   " + "file50.txt");
        while (file.hasNextLine())
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < (file.nextLine()).length(); b++)
            {
                if (!file.next().equals(" "))
                {
                    id = id + Integer.parseInt(file.next());
                    idStarted = true;
                }
                if (idStarted = true && file.next().equals(" "))
                {
                    idFinished = true; 
                }
                if (idFinished = true && !file.next().equals(" "))
                    inv = inv + Integer.parseInt(file.next());
            }
            String result = Integer.toString(id) + " " + Integer.toString(inv);
            myStore.add(result);
        }
    }       
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR:  File '" + "file50.txt" + "' not found!");
    }
    System.out.println(myStore);
}
```

}

The file looks like this:

```
  3679        87
   196        60
 17914        12
 18618        64
  2370        65
   584        85
 18524        34
 12024         5
  6992        76
 18410        56
  9267        68
 18995        56
  6265        58
  6835        94
 14151        82
 11485        39
 15559        33
 18465        27
 19967        45
 13520        38
  5529        11
  3433         5
 17911        96
 18181        60
 11549        88
 14896        81
   184        14
  4329        64
 18871        69
 15141        87
 11584        32
 14088        92
 18061         3
   206        31
 13066         8
 19623        88
 12705        14
  9351         8
 17753        70
 15917        51
   768        85
 15814        60
 15320        82
  8303        90
  7282        73
 14092        48
 10629        19
 12917        63
 15006        53
 12328        63
```

I can't see why that error is occurring at line 26:

```
if (!file.next().equals(" "))
```

What I'm trying to do there is check if the next object in a line is a blank space, and ignore it if that is the case. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Every single time you call a method that starts with `next` on that scanner you're reading from it. In at least two cases that immdiately jump out Glancing at your code you are throwing away what you've read

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the value of `file.next()` in a variable if you want to reuse it.

Calling next will increment where it is pointing.

try

```
String val = file.next ();

if (val.equals (" ")
   .

   .

 if (idStarted = true && val.equals(" "))
```

Comment: I see what you're saying here, and I implemented it, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: your use of nextLine is also going to cause this trouble.  Use getLine to get the string and then parse this string.  No more use of scanner should be required.

Answer (score 0):

you can trim the input you get and assign that to a string. then since there are only two indexes per line you can split that to an array with space delimiter and attach them together with space.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("test1/file50.txt"));
        System.out.println("File:   " + "file50.txt");
        while (file.hasNextLine())
        {
           String test = file.nextLine().trim();
           String[] array = test.split("\\s+");

            myStore.add(array[0]+" "+array[1]);
        }

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR:  File '" + "file50.txt" + "' not found!");
    }

    for(int i=0;i<myStore.size();i++){
        System.out.println(myStore.get(i));
    }

}
```